# Why 0/0 is NaN and not infinity in Javascript

Tags: javascript, divide-by-zero

Division by zero (`1/0`, `2/0`, `3/0`, etc) produces infinity. However `0/0` produces `NaN`. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mathematically it's most certainly *not* infinity. if it was obtained from limit x^2/x as x -> 0, it should be 0, for instance. x/x^2 would give infinity, though.

It's an indeterminate form, and in some sense *more* indeterminant than 1/0, 2/0 etc. In short, much more of your math would be mucked up from replacing 0/0 with Infinity than replacing 1/0 with infinity, because it's not clear that the denominator effect of dividing by zero should overwhelm the multiplication by zero effect of the numerator.